# Are mixed gender business Meetings Haram

Tags: halal-haram, business, non-mahram

I have a meeting for work this friday but I am a male and my boss is a female. I am going to lose my job if i dont go. i am 23 and my boss is 59. Is it haram to go?

Answer (score -1):

no, it would not be haram to go as free mixing of the genders is allowed. If you come from the beliefs that free mixing of the genders is not permissible, in this instance, where you will be in a professional/ formal environment, you should feel you are allow to attend this meeting with the intentions of fulfilling tasks of work or with the intention of working to provide.

Comment: But what if I want to date her? Then Is it haram?